# Django stops after 100 objects

Tags: python, django

I've made a small Django project and I want to compare the added objects against each other to find dublets (I already use the `unique_together` Meta options but that doesn't fit my need completely).

When i start the script it is finished after 100 iterations although there are around 60000 objects.

```
objects = Django_app.objects.all()

for object_a in objects:
    for object_b in objects:
        compare( object_a, object_b)
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

**Solution:**

```
objects = list( objects.all() )
```

Thanks to you all!

Comment: Is this the whole code? there may be a fault at some place inside the two loops

Comment: Please try evaluating the query set to list (`objects = list(objects)`) before entering the for loop and report what has happened.

Comment: @Aswin no its not but if tested it even with out everything in the loops and it still stops at 100

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz thanks! it now goes through objects. can you explain it? Is it because if a call objects.all() that there are no real objects and the first db connection is made wenn i call f.e. object_a.id ?

Comment: The iterator for `objects` is exhausted.

Comment: check out the documentation for django models at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/ section "When QuerySets are evaluated" it might be helpful too.

Comment: @Jakob Thanks for that hint! But is there a something in the documentation that describes the limitation of the iterator for QuerySets?

Comment: The hint for list(); somehow describes it:                `Be warned, though, that this could have a large memory overhead, because Django will load each element of the list into memory. In contrast, iterating over a QuerySet will take advantage of your database to load data and instantiate objects only as you need them.`

Answer (score 2):

When iterating over a list, Python uses a pointer to go through the list of objects. When iterating over the same object (the same list of items), Python takes care to use two separate pointers. So when you do `objects = list(objects)`, this creates a normal Python list of objects. A nested iteration over `objects` works like expected. With Django Querysets, the behavior is somewhat different. The Queryset is fetched from the database and there is only a single pointer. Forcing the Queryset into a regular list is the easiest workaround.